# how to enable systemd in x11 in yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, build-system

I am using `yocto(krogoth)` version and I have successfully compiled the images.
Distro:`imx-fls-x11`  &&  Image:`fsl-image-qt5`.
Now the issue is the `rootfs` is with `systemV` support now i want to use `systemd`. please help me to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your local.conf and add :

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_dev_manager = "systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""
```

It will set systemd as init daemon.

Answer (score 0):

To have systemd enable, you need to tweak your distro.

- add `systemd` to `DISTRO_FEATURES` and remove `sysvinit` from it
- set `VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"`

You can do it in local.conf or by customizing selected distro in meta-fsl-demos.